# Let  and  be real numbers. If  is irrational, then  is irrational or  is irrational

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Let  and  be real numbers. If  is irrational, then  is irrational or  is irrational.

Prove by contrapositive

I believe the contrapositive is if x is rational or y is rational, then xy is rational

How do I go about proving this?

Comment: The contrapositive is if x is rational AND y is rational, then xy is rational.

Comment: To give a name to the key step others have pointed out: the fact that negation swaps "or" and "and" is called **De Morgan's law**.

Comment: Beating a dead horse: not($A$ or $B$) $\implies$ It is not true that $A$ or $B\implies $ it is false that either $A$ or $B\implies$ it can not  be true that $A$ is true, or $B$ is true $\implies$ none of either $A$ nor $B$ can be true $\implies$ $A$ and $B$ must both be false $\implies$ (not $A$) and (not $B$).

Answer (score 1):

The contrapositive of ($xy$ is irrational $\implies x$ is irrational or $y$ is irrational) is:

$x$ is rational *and* $y$ is rational $\implies xy$ is rational.

Pf:  Let $x = \frac ab; a,b\in \mathbb Z$  And $y = \frac cd; c,d\in \mathbb Z$.

The $xy = \frac ab \frac cd = \frac {ac}{bd}$.  And $ac\in \mathbb Z$ and $bd\in \mathbb Z$ so $\frac {ac}{bd}$ is rational.

======

FWIW

It's worth having the following under your belt:

$rational \times rational = rational$.  Pf:  $\frac mn \frac jk = \frac {mj}{nk}$.

$\underbrace{rational}_{\text{not equal to zero}} \times irrational = irrational$.  Pf:  $\frac ab\times irrational=?????? \implies irrational = ????? \times \frac ba=?????\times rational$.  If $?????$ is rational then we have $irrational = rational\times rational$ which we *just* proved was impossible.

$irrational \times irrational = impossible\ to\ tell$.  Knowing that what each of the multiplicands *can't* be doesn't tell us what the product can or cant be.  Example $\sqrt 2 \times \sqrt 8=\sqrt{16} =4$.  But $\sqrt 2\times \sqrt 3 = \sqrt 6$.

Comment: That is overall nice, but don't forget to put the most important restriction: the denominator be non-zero.

Comment: If $x = \frac ab$ is defined then $b\ne 0$ and likewise $d\ne 0$.  So $bd =0$ is not an issue.

Comment: I know but it is always better to write it out, to get a error free proof.

Comment: Btw who edited this? It looks so horrible now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you got the contrapositive slightly (but significantly) wrong.

The negation of $x$ irrational OR $y$ irrational is (both) $x$ AND $y$ are rational.

Can you proceed from this point? Just let $x = \frac ab, y = \frac cd$.

Comment: Ah, thank you that was the big mistake. So I believe I can now say, xy = ab/cd, and thus it is rational because ab and cd are integers. Is it correct to assume that two integers multiplied together are also integers, or do I have to further prove that?

Comment: " Is it correct to assume that two integers multiplied together are also integers, or do I have to further prove that? "  That is a GREAT and intelligent question.  I suspect the class is assuming you can take that for given.  (It *might* be part of the definition of addition and multiplication. We say the integers are "closed" under addition/multiplication when every two integers always add/multiply to an integer.  That's *probably* your definition of addition and multiplication.)

Answer (score 0):

Your contrapositive should have *and*, not *or*, between "$x$ is rational" and "$y$ is rational". Otherwise it's correct, and the proof is direct: let $x=a/b,y=c/d$ and multiply.